# Maintain a std::vector parallel to std::map

Tags: c++, time-complexity

Recently, when I need to iterate through a `std::map` I usually build a `std::vector` from the map, since the complexity to access an element is (log N) (indeed, only when I need to access elements by a custom key).

So, I end up maintaining a `std::vector` just for iterating all my elements, (since its complexity is constant O(1)) and a `std::map` for specific retrieving (since its complexity is O(log n) when iterating).

Is this a correct way to do it, or should I just go with the `std::map` and forget about the `std::vector` (you know, for this specific case).

Thank you.

Comment: There's no "accessing". Searching for a single key in std::map is O(log n). Iterating over all elements in the map is O(n). What exactly does the vector do here?

Comment: Can you show the code with `std::map` which seems problematic for you ?

Comment: "since its complexity is O(log n) when iterating" - it's O(1) *amortized*.

Comment: Yes alright, it seems like I have some misunderstanding concepts about this. It's clear now, thank you so much.

Comment: You can also look into [Boost.MultiIndex](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_55_0/libs/multi_index/doc/index.html).

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You should forget about the `vector` unless profiling tells you you need it.  Iterating in a `map` is NOT O(log<sub>2</sub>N) per iterator increment... it only needs to find the next element by traversing the minimum path from the current element in the balanced binary tree... that's often only following a link or two, though the worst-case step of moving from the last left-side node to the first right-side node requires 2*(log<sub>2</sub>(N)-1) movements if it just uses a generic approach.

To visualise this, consider nodes in the map below - they're always in sorted order, and here I'm assuming the data elements happen to be incrementing integers as we can then easily refer to the nodes using their values:

```
                     8
                  /    \
                4        12
              /   \    /   \
             2    6    10   14
           /  \  / \  / \   / \
          1   3 5  7 9  11 13  15
```

As you traverse, your iterator may have to start at the root "8" and traverse the left hand branches to "1", but then it moves up a single link to 2, then down a single link to "3", before having to pop up a couple links to "4" and down a couple to "5".  Clearly - most of the time it's just following 1 or 2 links, with longer paths increasingly rare: if we list it all out:

```
6 links: once/x1: 7-6-4-8-12-19-9
3 links:  8-1
2 links: x4: 3-2-4, 4-6-5, 11-10-12, 12-14-13
1 link: x8: 1-2, 2-3, 5-6, 6-7, 9-10, 10-11, 13-14, 14-15
```

Total is 8*1 + 2*4 + 3*1 + 6*1 = 25... 25 links traversed to iterate 15 elements.

That sequence can be generalised for arbitrary N as: N/2 + 4N/8 + 6N/16 + 10N/32 + 12N/128 + 14N/256... 2iN/2<sup>i+1</sup>.... if we simplify the fractions and divide by N we get a series:

```
1/2, 1/2, 3/8, 1/4, 5/32, 3/32, 7/128, ...
```

There are lots of [proofs here](https://answers.yahoo.com/question/index?qid=20081114193152AAOtDzv) that it converses to 2N, i.e. the average number of links per increment of the iterator converges to 2 with large N, and as 2 is a constant factor we can still say incrementing the iterator is O(1).

Comment: Thank you, as I said in another comment, I was wrong about my understandings of time complexity for the `std::map` data structure ^^U.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12882424/in-order-traversal-complexity-in-a-binary-search-tree-using-iterators

Comment: @KarolyHorvath: thanks for the linked question - nice answer explaining how each node is visited at most 3 times! Cheers.

Comment: @Puyover: you're welcome... one of the more fun questions I've seen recently.